# Form calculation results adding too many zeros digits

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a major issue with a form calculation it work but suddelly keeping adding addional zeros, should be ""$4,000" no decimal but is like "26666.666666666668" here a piece of the code

```
<select Id="height" onChange="Calculate();">
          <option value=100>$1,000,000</option>
          <option selected="selected" value=200>$2,000,000</option>
          <option value=300>$3,000,000</option>
          <option  value=400>$4,000,000</option>
          <option value=500>$5,000,000</option>
          <option value=600>$6,000,000</option>
          <option value=700>$7,000,000</option>
          <option value=800>$8,000,000</option>
          <option value=900>$9,000,000</option>
          <option value=1000>$10,000,000</option>
        </select>

<input type="text" value="$3000" id="currency" name="example5">

<script language="javascript">


    function Calculate()
    {
        var h = document.getElementById('height').value;
        var l = document.getElementById('length').value;
        var v = document.getElementById('maxwidth').value;
        var  result= (h * l) * v / 12;
        document.getElementById('currency').value = "$" + result;
    }
</script>
```

Thank you.

Comment: What ere the elements "length" and "maxwidth"? They're not in your code

Answer (score 0):

parse your floating values to float like

```
 function Calculate()
{
    var h = document.getElementById('height').value;
    var l = document.getElementById('length').value;
    var v = document.getElementById('maxwidth').value;
    var  result= (parseFloat(h) * parseFloat(l)) * parseFloat(v) / 12;
    document.getElementById('currency').value = "$" + result;
}
```